# Jquery if / else if have 1 word

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I need to verify one var, if this var have a word what i need (not the whole var), send me a callback.

Example:

```
var text = "Tell the world i'm coming home.";

if(text == "world")
{
 alert("Ok!");
}
else
{
 alert("Nothing!");
}
```

Hmm, ideas?

Comment: Try reading up on regular expressions (you only need a really basic one here, but maybe the knowledge will be useful later) or have a look at [the functions available on JS strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String); [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) lets you test this pretty simply.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are asking about substring ooccurrence:

```
if(text.indexOf("world") != -1){
  alert("Ok!");
}
else
{
  alert("Nothing!");
}
```